# GNU Radio block with variable number of intputs/outputs

Tags: gnuradio

I am currently trying to do the signal processing of multiple channels in parallel using a custom source block. Up to now I created an OOT-source block which streams data for only one channel into one output perfectly fine.

Now I am searching for a way to expand this module so that it can support a higher number of channels ( = outputs of the source block; up to 64) in parallel. Because the protocol used to pull the samples pulls them all at one it is not possible to use more instances of the same source block.

Things I have found so far:

- A [pdf](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiS8o29tqLLAhXha3IKHa0EC6oQFggyMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmicroembedded.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FDesign_of_a_Block_with_Variable_Type_Inputs_and_Outputs.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHaIwTuomxzhwj6bzTlbEIk_ekVYg&sig2=IHYhZbpV7iuPOu0O6p_zyA&cad=rja) which seems to explain exactly what to do already but it seems that it is outdated and that this functionality is no longer supported under GNU Radio.
- The [description](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/issues/390) of a feature which should be implemented in the future.

Is there are known solution or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `add` block: It has configurable many inputs!

[image: Two different input configurations of the add block]

Now, the trick here is threefold:

1. define an `io_signature` as input and output that allows for adjustable numbers. If you use `gr_modtool add` to create a new block, your `io_signatures` will be filled with `<+MIN_IN+>`, `<+MAX_IN+>`, `<+MIN_OUT+>` and `<+MAX_OUT+>`. Adjust these to reflect your actual minimum and maximum in- and output port numbers. If you want to have `1` to `infinity` inputs, use `1`, `-1`.
2. in your (`general_`)`work` method, check for the number of inputs by doing something like `ninputs = input_items.size()`, and for the number of outputs by doing `noutputs = output_items.size()`.
3. (optionally, if you want to use GRC) modify the `<sink>`/`<source>` definitions in your block GRC XML:

   ```
   <sink>
           <name>in</name>
           <type>complex</type>
           <nports>$num_inputs</nports>
   </sink>
   ```

`num_inputs` could be a block parameter; [compare the `add_XX` block](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-blocks/grc/blocks_add_xx.xml) source code.